# Format list of tuples to 1 decimal

Tags: python

How would I format a number to always have 1 decimal place?  I have 4 numbers I want to add to a tuple, each having exactly 1 decimal place.  I tried messing around with .format but couldn't seem to get it to work with a tuple.

```
a = 1
b = 2
c = 3
d = 4.44
my_tup = (a,b,c,d)
```

And I want my_tup to be formatted like so.
    (1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4,4)

Thanks for the help!

Comment: you are not formatting a tuple. you are formatting a series of numbers inside a tuple. Also, tuples are immutable, so you want to do that before putting them in the tuple. Also, it is not clear from your question if you want to format the numbers, or to trim them. (as in the latter case, 1 == 1.0)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
a, b, c, d = 1, 2, 3, 4.44
my_tup = (a, b, c, d)
my_tup = tuple([float("{0:.1f}".format(n)) for n in my_tup])
```

However, [`tuple`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#tuple) is an immutable sequence so you can't change it after you have created it. It's probably better to have your numbers formatted correctly before you put them in a tuple; this will also avoid the whole (ugly) create a `list` then create a `tuple` from it in `tuple([float("{0:.1f}".format(n)) for n in my_tup])`

Comment: the other solve for creating a tuple from a list in your case is `map("{:.1f}".format, my_tup)`, as in my solution. I prefer `decimal.Decimal` though since these numbers should explicitly avoid floating point math! Great answer though, +1

Answer (score 1):

If you are only want to see the numbers with one decimal place visually, but preserve the accuracy, use the string formatting:

```
print "%.1f" % number
```

If you want to round the number:
    math.round(number,1)

math.floor and math.ceil will allow to round strictly down or up

Answer (score 0):

`decimal` is the proper solution, since these are decimal numbers not floating point.

```
import decimal

a, b, c, d = 1, 2, 3, 4.44
my_tup = tuple(map(decimal.Decimal, map("{:.1f}".format, [a,b,c,d])))
```

This is basically just:

```
a, b, c, d = 1, 2, 3, 4.44

# strip the nonsignificant digits
a = "{:.1f}".format(a) # 1.0
b = "{:.1f}".format(b) # 2.0
c = "{:.1f}".format(c) # 3.0
d = "{:.1f}".format(d) # 4.4

my_tup = (decimal.Decimal(a), decimal.Decimal(b),
          decimal.Decimal(c), decimal.Decimal(d))
```